# Pattern constraints for a list of strings

Tags: java, regex

I have a `List<String>` that contains a list of emails, something like
`{"email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"}`

The problem is I don't really know how to create a @Pattern, and I want to put the condition that the pattern should only allow emails from list that ends with `@gmail.com`. I used

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(.+)@(.+)$")
```

for the case when I had a String, not a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to refer to the documentation of **Container element constraints**.

```
List<@Pattern(regexp = "^(.+)@(gmail.com)$") String> mails;
```

Reference: https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-containerelementconstraints